# c# Save Streamwriter after every 200 Cycles without Closing

Tags: c#, file, save

I'm using a StreamWriter to write some data to a file.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
while(something_is_happening && my_flag_is_true)
     file.WriteLine(some_text_goes_Inside);

file.close();
```

What i noticed is, till the close is called no data is written to the file.

Is there any way i can save the contents to the file before closing.

Comment: Just a hint : you should use the `using` statement for your streamwriter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose you can use Flush method.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
int counter = 0;
while(something_is_happening && my_flag_is_true)
{
    file.WriteLine(some_text_goes_Inside);
    counter++;
    if(counter < 200) continue;
    file.Flush();
    counter = 0;
}
file.Close();
```

For more information welcome to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for [Flush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
file.Flush();
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Call [`Flush()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) to force buffers to be written:

```
file.Flush();
```

> Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data
>   to be written to the underlying stream.

Or set [AutoFlush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx) property

```
file.AutoFlush = true;
```

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the StreamWriter will flush
>   its buffer to the underlying stream after every call to
>   StreamWriter.Write.

Answer (score 2):

Cycle:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
for (int i = 0; true && flag; i++)
{
    file.WriteLine(some_text_goes_Inside);
    if (i == 200)
    {
        file.Flush();
        i = 0;
    }
}
file.Close();
```